# Image from array is not appended to <div> id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, image

I have an array of images and when the content page is loaded. One picture from the array will be appended to the `<div>` `id` and be displayed.

```js
var GameQuestion = ["A?", "B?", "C?"];

var GameAnswer = [
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"],
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"],
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"]
];

var answerList,
  random_Question;

random_Question = Math.floor(Math.random() * GameQuestion.length);

$("#question").html(GameQuestion[random_Question]);

answerList = GameAnswer[random_Question];

$("#Answer_1").html(answerList[0]);
$("#Answer_2").html(answerList[1]);
```

```html
<!-- Original Question -->
<div id="question" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:750px; left:160px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:30px; width:800px; text-align: center;"></div>

<!-- Answer-Original-Choice List -->
<div id="Answer_1" class="answers" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1006px; left:224px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px;"></div>
<div id="Answer_2" class="answers" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1186px; left:224px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px;"></div>
```

When the content page loads, I am only able to see the question, however, the part where the image should be appended and displayed. It is only showing the file path name.

hence, if the content page loads the Question: A?, the 2 image id should load and display the image of True & False. However at this point, I am only seeing the file path name of "lib/True.png" and "lib/False.png" for img id "Answer_1" and "Answer_2".

Therefore, what is wrong? As I would need the img ids to display the image instead of showing the file path name.

Please help. thankyou

Comment: Where exactly is your `<img>`...?

Comment: @Gothdo, sorry, it was meant to be a <div>, am getting too groggy

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create an `<img>` with a `src` attribute. There are several ways to to this, of which creating an HTML string is a pretty straight forward one:

```
$("#Answer_1").html("<img src='" + answerList[0] + "'/>")
```

This will create a string like `"<img src='lib/False.png'/>"`. The jQuery `html` method will put this inside your `#Answer_1` div and the browser will parse it as HTML.

A better approach might be to already create the `<img>` tags and only update the `src` attribute. Your HTML would be something like:

```
<div><img id="Answer_1" /></div>
```

With js:

```
$("#Answer_1").attr("src", answerList[0]);
```

Now, the browser doesn't have to remove/inject a new image every time you do this.

(Note that the images won't work in a snippet)

```js
var GameQuestion = ["A?", "B?", "C?"];

var GameAnswer = [
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"],
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"],
  ["lib/True.png", "lib/False.png"]
];

var answerList,
  random_Question;

random_Question = Math.floor(Math.random() * GameQuestion.length);

$("#question").html(GameQuestion[random_Question]);

answerList = GameAnswer[random_Question];

$("#Answer_1").html("<img src='" + answerList[0] + "'/>");
$("#Answer_2").html("<img src='" + answerList[1] + "'/>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Original Question -->
<div id="question" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:750px; left:160px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:30px; width:800px; text-align: center;"></div>

<!-- Answer-Original-Choice List -->
<div id="Answer_1" class="answers" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1006px; left:224px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px;"></div>
<div id="Answer_2" class="answers" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1186px; left:224px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px;"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, i meant to append it to the <div> id tag